# Why airflow scheduler and airflow webserver cant work together?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, airflow

I run command `airflow webserver` in one terminal and it works well.
But when I run `airflow scheduler` in another terminal it stops webserver and can`t run scheduler too. I tried to change webserver port to 8070 but it still stucks.

Comment: please provide more details. os ? logs ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.